# Logrotate: Message in log configuration file for rotation

Tags: logrotate

I am trying to make a configuration file for rotation in /etc/logrotate.d/
I did this:

```
 sudo cat > service
 /var/log/service/service.log {
 rotate 6
 compress
 size=120M
 missingok
 create 0777 root root
 notifempty
 }
```

I want to add message after rotation with current date and time, some text (for e.g "Complete") in file /var/log/logrotate.log . How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `postrotate` command before the final `}` eg:

```
postrotate
 exec >> /var/log/logrotate.log
 date; echo 'completed'
endscript
```

This part is only executed (by `/bin/sh`) if the log file is actually rotated.